# Class with changing __hash__ still works with dictionary access

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What I did is obviously not something that one would want to do, rather, I was just testing out implementing `__hash__` for a given class.

I wanted to see if adding a phony 'hashable' class to a dictionary, then changing it's hash value would then result in it not being able to access it.

My class looks like this:

```
class PhonyHash:

    def __hash__(self):
        val = list("A string")
        return id(val)  # always different
```

Executing the following in my `IPython` console:

```
>>> p = PhonyHash()
>>> d = { p: "a value"}
>>> hash(p)  # changes hash
```

and then trying to access the element with `d[p]` works:

```
>>> d[p]
"a value"
```

I understand, this is not something that should be done, I'm really just curious as to why it works. Doesn't `dict` use the `hash()` of an object to store/retrieve it? Why is this working?

**edit:** as noted in the comments by @VPfB `sets` behave as expected, for some reason:

```
>>> p = PhonyHash()
>>> s = {p}
>>> p in s
False
```

Comment: The `id` of `p` does not change. That's also something to consider

Comment: That I am aware of but is not something that troubles me. `id`s of mutable objects also doesn't change after you mutate them.

Comment: Call the hash function on its own. How much does the value change?

Comment: It looks like this does not work reliable. If you add many other objects to the dict you will get an KeyError. I would assume that the mechanism that deals with hash-collisions "accidentally" makes this work.

Comment: It behaves as expected in a set. `s={p}` and then `p in s` returns False.

Comment: What is `p.hash` I don't see this method defined

Comment: My mistake @wim, it was supposed to call `hash`, fixed now.

Comment: I think you might eventually get a KeyError due to the post-processing of hash values that don't fit in a `Py_ssize_t`, particularly if you're on a 32-bit Python build and you create tons and tons of objects to fill up your address space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a strange bit of fate. Several bits of CPython machinery have thwarted you. The three issues at play are:

1. The initial size of the array that backs a `dict` is 8 <sup>[1]</sup>
2. All objects in CPython have memory addresses that are modulo 8 <sup>[2]</sup>
3. The `dict` class has an optimisation that checks keys are the same object and stops there if true (otherwise it will check if they are equal according to the `__eq__` method) <sup>[3]</sup>

What this means is that despite your object always producing different hash values, the first slot of the backing array that will be examined is the same. If it wasn't you'd get a key error because the slot was empty. The `dict` then decides it has the right key because it has the exact same object, not just an equal object.

```
class PhonyHash:
    _hash = 1
    def __hash__(self):
        return self._hash

p = PhonyHash()
d = {p: "val"}
print(p in d) # True
p._hash = 2
print(p in d) # False
p._hash = 9 # 9 % 8 == 1
print(p in d) # True
```

#### Links to CPython sources

1. The `dict` [struct](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Include/dictobject.h#L69) defines `ma_table`, which starts as `ma_smalltable`, which is of length [PyDict_MinSize](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Include/dictobject.h#L48).
2. This is documented in [Objects/obmalloc.c](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/obmalloc.c#L81)
3. Can be seen in the lookup function [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L310) and [here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L346)

Comment: You should see what OP's case: `id(list('a string'))` returns with multiple calls

Comment: Hmm, very true. Just found out why this weird fluke works though.

Comment: The id does actually change between calls in OP's case, at least on my python 3 installation, but: it doesn't change enough and with such a small dictionary the differences don't matter, as the larger hash is compacted to the dictionary's smaller size. Try using the `PhonyHash` object as key with a dictionary created with `d = dict.fromkeys(range(1406185))`.

Comment: I found the reason why it changes and still works. The minimum size of the table that backs a `dict` is 8. And more often than not, objects have the same modulo 8 result. So despite the hash being different, the first place the dict looks is where the object is, they are equal by reference so the dict doesn't bother checking for hash equality or `__eq__` equality.

Comment: That's quite obvious if one keeps on trying with your counter version. It works every 8th attempt :P

Comment: How about some cpython source links for 1. - 3. ?

Comment: @wim done, took me a while to track down the memory address one.

Answer (score 3):

I have a possible explanation:

According to this source: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/ only few last bits of the hash are used when the table holding the dict elements is small.

The id() number is ususally a machine address and is very probably alligned to some memory address boundary. So the last few bits are always zero and not random at all. In the result, you are always hitting table[0] element.

Trying a different source of a random phony hash changes the situation and the expected KeyError is thrown.

---

EDIT: Dunes answered the question the same way and he was quicker than me.